# Are the reasons why the NED chose to fund a certain organization made publicly available?

Tags: united-states, democracy, funding, ngos

> NED is a grant-making foundation, distributing funds to private
> non-governmental organizations for promoting democracy abroad in
> around 90 countries. Half of NED's funding is allocated annually to
> four main U.S. organizations: the American Center for International
> Labor Solidarity (associated with the AFL–CIO), the Center for
> International Private Enterprise (affiliated with the USCC), the
> National Democratic Institute for International Affairs (associated
> with the Democratic Party), and the International Republican Institute
> (formerly known as the National Republican Institute for International
> Affairs and affiliated with the Republican Party).[22] The other half
> of NED's funding is awarded annually to hundreds of non-governmental
> organizations based abroad which apply for support.[23] In 2011, the
> Democratic and Republican Institutes channeled around $100 million a
> year through the NED.[16]

> The NED receives an annual appropriation from the U.S. budget (it is included in the chapter of the Department of State budget destined for the U.S. Agency for International Development-USAID) and is subject to congressional oversight even as a non-governmental organization. In the financial year to the end of September 2009 NED had an income of $135.5 million, nearly all of which came from U.S Government agencies.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Endowment_for_Democracy

I was trying to find out how the board members decided which organizations to fund and if the discussion that determined the outcome was also made publicly available, but I couldn't really find anything about it. How does the organization determine who gets the money and how transparent are they?

Comment: Please spell out all acronyms at least once. All three letter acronyms have many multiple meanings.